# get last element id number in JQuery and plus one

Tags: jquery

how can i get the last id number of below code dynamically? (in this code = obj_9)

```
            <div id="objects">
            <div class="obj_item"><img id="obj_1" class="ui-widget-content" src="elements/abstract_celtic_knot_in_blue_tattoo_design.png" /></div>
            <div class="obj_item"><img id="obj_2" class="ui-widget-content" src="elements/anchor_tears_the_skin_tatoo_design.png" /></div>
            <div class="obj_item"><img id="obj_3" class="ui-widget-content" src="elements/armband_tattoo_with_cross_in_the_center_idea.png" /></div>
            <div class="obj_item"><img id="obj_4" class="ui-widget-content" src="elements/armband_tribal_sign_tattoo_design.png" /></div>
            <div class="obj_item"><img id="obj_5" class="ui-widget-content" src="elements/bat_covered_by_the_wings_tattoo_design.png" /></div>
            <div class="obj_item"><img id="obj_6" class="ui-widget-content" src="elements/black_eye_tattoo_idea.png" /></div>
            <div class="obj_item"><img id="obj_7" class="ui-widget-content" src="elements/black_sketch_of_native_indian_chief_tattoo_design.png" /></div>
            <div class="obj_item"><img id="obj_8" class="ui-widget-content" src="elements/clown_with_two_knives_tattoo_idea.png" /></div>
            <div class="obj_item"><img id="obj_9" class="ui-widget-content" src="elements/eagle_is_catching_prey_tattoo_design.png" /></div>
            </div>
```

and finally convert id to int number and plus it one.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they're in numeric order, this will get the numeric value + 1 of the ID of the last image element...

```
parseInt($("#objects .obj_item:last img").attr("ID").split("_")[1], 10) + 1;
```

If the elements could ever be out of order then this won't work and you'd need to parse them all and find the highest value.

Answer (score 0):

if you always start to assign `id` from `1` and there's no missing id in the middle, just try

```
var newID = "obj_" + ( $('#objects > div').length + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it...

The sudo selector :last is key.

```
var id = parseInt($('#objects .ob_item:last').find('.ui-widget-content').attr('id'));
id = id + 1;

//Or id++
```

Comment: thank you your code working but it return "obj_91" instead "obj_10".

Comment: d'oh, data types! I have amended for you :)

Comment: parseInt("obj_9") + 1 does not yield the result 10. parseInt stops at the first none digit character (where the radix determines what is considered a digit)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var last_id = $('#objects div.obj_item > img').last().attr('id');
});
```

You can also do :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var last_id = $('#objects div.obj_item > img:last').attr('id');
});
```

Comment: you are looking for the img in the last div.obj_item however the last selector looks for the last img in any div.obj_item which is (at least) semantically different

Comment: Yes, but regarding the HTML posted by @SinaZhr, it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of psuedo code off of the top of my head...

```
   var id = "";
$(".obj_item").each(function(index){
var amount = $(".obj_item").length;
if(index == amount-1){

id = $(this).find("img").attr("id");
    alert(parseInt(id.replace("obj_","")));
}
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

you'd first need to find the last element. There's quite a few ways to slice that cake. I'd prefer

```
var id = $("#objects .obj_item:last img").attr("ID");
```

the you'd need to extract the number

```
var num = parseInt(id.substring(3),10);
```

add you can then add 1 to num

the last argument to parseInt is the radix telling the runtime to parse the string as a decimal number. You can get some unexpected results if you do not supply this argument. Whether or not those situations could arise depends on how you generate the IDs but regardless it's a good habit to always supply the radix.

Comment: thanks, its return "Nan" why?                               id = $('#objects div.obj_item:last').find('img.ui-widget-content').attr('id'); 
   num = parseInt(id.substring(3),10);
   imgid = num + 1;

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expression:

```
$("#objects >div:last img")[0].id.replace(/[a-z]+_/gi,"")
```